# Why do career inbox notification mails not contain the full text?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

Emails from careers.stackoverflow.com tell me that someone sent me a message, but do not contain the content. I have to open the browser to view the message.

Why can't the mail simply contain the message the company sent me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 3):

It probably can, with some extra work on our part.  The primary reason now is that we want to encourage candidates to reply to a message sent, even if that message is negative (Not Interested).  The short way to do that was to get people in app to make that choice.

I do recognize there are ways to do this directly from the email client in most cases, but it's a bit harder.

We'll look into this more when we get some messaging features in the schedule.